# Exposing read-only dependency properties on a control who's values come from children controls in the ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a Control, FooControl. It needs to expose a read-only DependencyProperty called HasError. The value of this property is actually just the value from a control in FooControl's ControlTemplate.

The following code accomplishes exactly what I want, except it forces me to declare FooControl.HasError as a read-write DependencyProperty (the Binding cannot set the value otherwise.)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="FooControl">
    <ChildControl HasError="{Binding HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

I'm trying to get around having to do annoying stuff like using PART_'s to find the child control, attach to its HasError ValueChanged event, and copy the value. Because that's obnoxious, and I have quite a few properties like this.

Comment: I assume you are using Validation on the underlying control and want to expose it through dependency properties? What might help is the fact that the Validation class has static methods used to get the error from a control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.gethaserror.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the dependency property `ChildControl.HasError` defines the framework property metadata option `BindsTwoWayByDefault`. This means that the mode of `{Binding HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}` is `TwoWay`, which does not work when the source property is read-only.

Therefore, change the binding to

```
{Binding HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}
```

This overrides `BindsTwoWayByDefault` and the binding should work.

Comment: You can use a `TwoWay` data binding only if both properties are writable. The purpose of a data binding is to change the value of a property T when the property S changes. Therefore T must be writable; a TwoWay binding adds a mirrored relationship where T acts as S and S acts as T; i.e. in a TwoWay binding both S and T must be writable.

Comment: I know. I said as much in my original question. So I'm trying to find a proper way to accomplish what I want. Perhaps there is no good way other than using PART stuff.